# Scrollbar on Android

Tags: android, css, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I'm using `-webkit-scrollbar` property to show scrollbars at iOS and Android but when I'm scrolling the container on a Android device the content flickers according to scrollbar width.

How can I solve this?

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a bit of Javascript.

```
<script>
    // Add a .touch or .no-touch class to <html> based on device capability
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('class',
        'ontouchend' in document ? 'touch' : 'no-touch');
</script>
```

(Ensure that this line is placed **before the CSS** -- desktop browsers will not style the CSS otherwise.)

Pre-fix the `::webkit-scrollbar-*` with a `.no-touch` class to ensure that only non-touch devices get the scrollbar style, and Android does not.

```
.no-touch ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px; 
}
.no-touch ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
/* ... etc */
```

Now, non-touch devices will see a styled scrollbar. Touch devices will not.